# Changed workplace in eclipse but can't run programs

Tags: eclipse

**Eclipse IDE**

Today I decided to change my organisation method a little bit and decided to create projects for some exercises I was doing.

Let's say I had them in folder "Subjects" to which I creater a subfolder "SubjectA".

Problem:

After changing the workplace from Subjects to SubjectA I can't run my programs from the other subjects or anything outside SubjectA, is there a way to do it wihtouth having to import them to SubjectA ( as it wouldn't make sense)?

If not, do I have to keep changing the new java project location everytime I want  to create a new one from different subjects (as I can't set my workplace to something more specific)?

Sorry for the silly question but I wasn't beeing able to find any similar ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest instead of using different workspace you can use different projects or packages.

In Java project, you can store all the information related to a specific project.

A java package is a group of similar types of classes, interfaces and sub-packages.

so you can either create multiple packages or projects like

> Workspace
>
> --------->Project 1->src
>
> .              ------>com.package.one
>                 ------>com.package.two

or you can do something like

> Workspace
>
> ---------->Project1
>
> ---------->Project2